# Why do != and <> both exist in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

As you might imagine, I'm having a hard time Googlin' for this, does anyone know why `<>` and `!=` both exist, especially if [they're identical](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/functions-comparison.html)?

My best guess is one is SQL standard or it's historical, but I was hoping someone knew the actual reason. This might apply to more than postgres also...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official SQL standard operator for inequality is `<>`, but due to the popularity of C and C-like languages (eg java), practically all databases support `!=` as an alternative for `<>`.

There is no effective difference between them.